# Genexus Transmitir mensagem via sistema para outro usuário

Tags: genexus

Preciso transmitir mensagem via sistema para outro usuário do sistema, um alerta na verdade. Alguém tem alguma ideia? Desenvolvido em .NET o sistema, utilizo IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que você poderia resolver usando WebNotifications, você pode encontrar informações e exemplos http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22442,WebNotifications+external+object

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. E apenas para Genexus 15?

Comment: En ev3 hay una solución equivalente:http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32301,WebNotifications+external+object+%28X+Evolution+3%29